# can not resolve symbol package name while creating library

Tags: java, android, jar

I want to create a library and .jar file to use this into another project, for creating library and .jar file i'm following [this](http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-to-create-and-use-jar-archive-using.html) tutorial, but when i'm copying my classes in to library module i got error, **can not resolve symbol Color** for **import android.graphics.Color** and for all other package i got  same error,

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
```

and while build

```
/local_dir/newFolder/../../src/main/java/com/../Utils.java
Error:(3, 23) error: package android.content does not exist
Error:(4, 27) error: package android.content.res does not exist
Error:(5, 24) error: package android.graphics does not exist
Error:(6, 24) error: package android.graphics does not exist
Error:(7, 24) error: package android.graphics does not exist
Error:(8, 33) error: package android.graphics.drawable does not exist
Error:(9, 20) error: package android.util does not exist
Error:(10, 20) error: package android.util does not exist
Error:(11, 20) error: package android.view does not exist
Error:(21, 20) error: cannot find symbol class DisplayMetrics
Error:(33, 29) error: cannot find symbol class Context
Error:(91, 37) error: cannot find symbol class Paint
Error:(95, 20) error: cannot find symbol class Rect
Error:(97, 38) error: cannot find symbol class Paint
Error:(132, 25) error: package Paint does not exist
Error:(134, 39) error: cannot find symbol class Paint
Error:(138, 39) error: cannot find symbol class Paint
Error:(138, 57) error: package Paint does not exist
Error:(143, 40) error: cannot find symbol class Paint
Error:(147, 40) error: cannot find symbol class Paint
Error:(147, 58) error: package Paint does not exist
Error:(152, 38) error: cannot find symbol class Paint
Error:(159, 20) error: cannot find symbol class Rect
Error:(168, 37) error: cannot find symbol class Paint
Error:(196, 20) error: cannot find symbol class Rect
Error:(198, 34) error: cannot find symbol class Canvas
Error:(199, 34) error: cannot find symbol class Drawable
```

I want to create a library .jar file to use it into another project, so how to solve this error ? or any other way to create library .jar file?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks! A link to an external tutorial is **not** enough. Please describe clearly which steps you took.

Answer (score 0):

its seems dependent jars are not at class path
while creating jar from your library all  dependent classes jars should in class path.